# 2012 Ford Escape A/C blowing hot and lowest blower speed not working

Tags: ford, ac, escape

My A/C started blowing hot air intermittently the other day. Of course, the day I take it in to the mechanic it starts to work like normal. My mechanic said there were no issues he could find except maybe too much Freon in the system and the A/C froze up.

With some more testing, I learned that the blower doesn't work on the lowest speed. My guess is that the A/C froze up because the nonfunctional blower was not moving the cold air into the cabin.

- Speed 1 = NOT blowing
- Speed 2-4 = Blowing

From my online searching, it sounds like I need to replace the [blower resister pack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L2hsbQiG8I). I ordered a new part and will report back if that fixes my problem.

Comment: To my knowledge, if the resistor pack was at fault, blower speed 1 would not work on any of the modes. There's only one resistor pack which controls the blower speed. Max A/C should have no effect on this at all. Please do tell us if the resistor pack makes a difference, but my bet is that it won't.

Comment: You are correct. I thought I was feeling a little air blowing through the vents on the lowest speed, but it wasn't. After I replaced the resistor pack, it was obvious the lowest speed wasn't working before. I updated the question with this detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the blower resistor pack was to blame. I replaced the part behind the glove box and now all the blower speeds work.

Observer Note: I tested the blower after taking out the old resistor pack and only the highest blower setting worked. I tested the blower again with the new resistor pack before screwing it in place to confirm it worked correctly. Wow, that resistor pack got warm. I can see why these things go bad over time.